# How to search for Oracle DB entries that have changed from a certain point in time?

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison, version

I'm trying to search for security privileges that have been changed for users after a certain point of time. For example, I want to find what was changed after 01.03.2020 for the users.

Is there a way to look at the current security privileges and then compare with what they had before 01.03.2020? The database table holds all the changes, with a version number for each change in security privileges. However, I can't just compare the current with the previous version, I need to look at a certain period, i.e. after 01.03.2020. The table has the following columns:

```
user_id
security_privilege_id
version_number
last_user_update_id
last_update
```

Below an example of what I want to search for. For this user_id, I want to compare the latest security privileges (version 16) with the security privileges BEFORE 01.03.2020. So in that case it will compare version 16 with version 14. It needs to identify all cases where security privileges changed between the versions.

[image: sample data]

Comment: Some sample data would help a lot.

Comment: I added more info. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This answers a reasonable interpretation of the original question.

No, it is not possible.  Your table only contains the most recent data along with the `update` timestamp.

In order to answer your question, you need more information about what the data looked like at a particular point in time.  Three common methods of implementing this are:

- A type-2 table.  That is a table with a version effective and end date that shows what the values are at a given point in time.
- An audit table.  This is a table that shows the before and after pictures of the data for an update.
- Snapshot tables, which stash away what the table looks like at a particular point in time.

Your table doesn't seem to have this information, so it cannot be used to answer the question.  It is possible that other tables in your database *do* have the information, but your question does not mention them.

Comment: Probably I was not clear. That table CONTAINS all the historical entries. These are saved as different versions! So I want to compare the latest security privileges for each user with the previous entries before a certain date, e.g. 01.03.2020.

Comment: To repeat @William Robertson - "some sample data would help".  Update your question, adding the DDL to recreate your table, and some INSERT statements to create representative data.  That will allow people to test out answers before submitting them.  Help us to help you.

Comment: INSERT INTO security_privileges (
 user_id
 ,security_privilege_id
 ,version_number
 ,last_user_update_id
 ,last_update
 )
VALUES (
 9867
 ,2145
 ,3
 ,9954
 ,'01.09.2020'
 )

Comment: @Skywalker . . . No, I don't think your table does, at least not as "update" is normally used in SQL.  Your question and table structure implies that rows are **updated**, not that new values are **inserted**.  The common terminology for a timestamp on an insert is "createdAt" or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I can't really look into the INSERT statement, as that table is core table in the system. I guess that's what it's going. All these entries are generated by the system when the admin user changes in the GUI the security privileges for the other users. Not sure why the discussion when this direction? My question was around querying that table. It keeps all the history, meaning all the previous security privileges per user, and when they were changed.

Comment: @Skywalker . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want.  A misleading column name such as `update_date` needs particular explanation.

Comment: Ok, just added more information. Hopefully, now it's more clear. Thanks